# dotnet sdk is installed but not recognized - Linux Ubuntu/popOS 22.04

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, ubuntu

I had the dotnet sdk working just fine yesterday, today when I login to my PC, I update the system and VSCode and then when I tried running `dotnet watch run`, I got this error:

```
  * You intended to execute a .NET application:
      The application 'watch' does not exist.
  * You intended to execute a .NET SDK command:
      No .NET SDKs were found.

Download a .NET SDK:
https://aka.ms/dotnet-download

Learn about SDK resolution:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/sdk-not-found
```

Here is what happens when I try to do an apt install of the sdk(It shows already installed):

```
sudo apt install dotnet-sdk-6.0
[sudo] password for robinson: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
dotnet-sdk-6.0 is already the newest version (6.0.400-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

Here is my `dotnet --info`:

```
global.json file:
  Not found

Host:
  Version:      6.0.8
  Architecture: x64
  Commit:       55fb7ef977

.NET SDKs installed:
  No SDKs were found.

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.8 [/usr/lib/dotnet/dotnet6-6.0.108/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.8 [/usr/lib/dotnet/dotnet6-6.0.108/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

From my googling, it seems it may be PATH issue, but I tried adding a few different paths and it still didn't work.
here is the which dotnet:

```
/usr/bin/dotnet
```

And my echo path:

```
/home/robinson/.nvm/versions/node/v18.7.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/robinson/.dotnet/tools
```

I'm a linux noob, any help is appreciated. I'm running popOS on an x64 computer.

Comment: I was also facing the same issue. Resolved it by adding `DOTNET_ROOT=/usr/lib/dotnet` into my `.zshrc` file. If you are using `bash` you will have to update your `.bashrc` file.

Answer (score 183):

I had the same problem, and here's what I did to resolve it.

1. Removed all .NET packages 
    `sudo apt remove 'dotnet*'`
   `sudo apt remove 'aspnetcore*'`
2. Deleted PMC repository from APT, by deleting the repo .list file 
    `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-prod.list`
3. Ran `sudo apt update`
4. Installed .NET 6 SDK via `sudo apt install dotnet-sdk-6.0`

This is one of the solutions provided on the Github issues page for dotnet/core, please follow the original article if the above did not work for you.
https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/7699

Comment: I faced the same issue this morning and did what you suggested. It worked for me. It allowed me to install sdk version `6.0.108 [/usr/lib/dotnet/dotnet6-6.0.108/sdk]`, but not the latest one (sdk 6.0.400) which caused this issue I guess.

Comment: @slanto Yes, I think that's the latest available in Jammy packages. Also I edited my response, I had mistakenly pasted the same remove command twice earlier.

Comment: this worked with 108 version installed. prob cause they removed 400 due bug?

Comment: No, they released net6 in official Ubuntu 22.04 (Jammy) packages (https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/dotnet-6-is-now-in-ubuntu-2204/), but they are using the 6.0.1xx series SDK, the PMC (packages.microsoft.com) version is on the 6.0.4xx series SDK.  See https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/7699 for details.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/74688

Comment: Thanks that works for me on Ubuntu 22.04 and sdk-7.0

Comment: Thanks! Same here, and I also run Ubuntu 22.04 and dotnet-sdk-7.0

Answer (score 37):

There is some package version [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/27082#issuecomment-1211143446), use this to get dotnet-sdk working again

## Update

Dotnet is now part of some ubuntu repo and there are glitches on dist upgrading ubuntu, using https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/7699#issuecomment-1288131522 removes the ms repo, its packages and installs dotnet from the canonical repo.

```bash
sudo snap remove dotnet-sdk
sudo apt remove 'dotnet*'
sudo apt remove 'aspnetcore*'
sudo apt remove 'netstandard*'
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-prod.list
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-prod.list.save
sudo apt update
sudo apt install dotnet6
```

## Old

```
$ sudo apt install aspnetcore-runtime-6.0=6.0.8-1 dotnet-apphost-pack-6.0=6.0.8-1 dotnet-host=6.0.8-1 dotnet-hostfxr-6.0=6.0.8-1 dotnet-runtime-6.0=6.0.8-1 dotnet-sdk-6.0=6.0.400-1 dotnet-targeting-pack-6.0=6.0.8-1
```

<s>I hope that will be fixed soon.</s>

https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/7699 brings some light into the issue.

Comment: After trying a lot of other things (including all the answers with more upvotes than this one) this finally solved the problem for me. Many many thanks!

Comment: Thanks! This also worked for me using dotnet7 instead. Linux Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: this worked for me. I also followed the instructions at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/remove-runtime-sdk-versions?pivots=os-linux#uninstall-net to remove previous versions, prior to reinstall everything

Comment: dear sir, you are my saviour! 

Answer (score 8):

i had this issue - if you using .net 7 this script will work for you

```
sudo snap remove dotnet-sdk && sudo apt remove -y 'dotnet*' 'aspnetcore*' 'netstandard*' && sudo rm -f /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-prod.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-prod.list.save && sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y dotnet7
```

Comment: worked for me. Seems like Microsoft apt source was the culprit.

Comment: That solved it for me too. Instead of following microsoft's instructions just apt install dotnetXX did it.

Answer (score 6):

So I ended up solving the issue as well by doing the following:
I uninstalled everything I could that was dotnet related with: `sudo apt remove 'dotnet*'`
Then I did a `sudo apt autoremove` and `sudo apt update`.

Then I followed the instructions [on this link](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/sdk-6.0.400-linux-x64-binaries) to unpack the binaries straight into the /opt/ folder. Once I added the necessary lines to PATH (according to the instructions in the link), everything worked as expected.

I would however recommend following the instructions by Saranga first as using the package manager might be the better solution.
Thank you everyone.

Comment: Is this a "clean" way of doing things? Your method is what worked for me, but I'm afraid it's only temporary.

Answer (score 6):

Here's what I did to fix it:

Removed all .NET packages

`sudo apt remove 'dotnet*'`

`sudo apt remove 'aspnetcore*'`

Deleted PMC repository from APT, by deleting the repo .list file

`sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-prod.list`

Ran

`sudo apt update`

Installed .NET 6 SDK via the install script:

(follow the instructions carefully!)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-scripted-manual#scripted-install

Modified my ~/.bashrc so at the end of the file it has:

`export PATH="$PATH:/home/INSERT_YOUR_USERNAME_HERE/.dotnet"`

Now everything is working again.

Answer (score 3):

in my case it was already installed, but it did not recognize it because it was in another location apparently.

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/core/install/linux-snap
```

According to the documentation, I installed it through snap and this was the solution with this command

```
sudo ln -s /snap/dotnet-sdk/current/dotnet /usr/local/bin/dotnet
```

in UBUNTU 22.04, .NET6.0

Comment: simple and straightforward thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to setup your DOTNET_ROOT according to Base Path: /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.101/

```bash
osanhaji@5CD2068Y53:~ $ dotnet --info
.NET SDK:
 Version:   7.0.101
 Commit:    bb24aafa11

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     ubuntu
 OS Version:  22.04
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         ubuntu.22.04-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.101/

Host:
  Version:      7.0.1
  Architecture: x64
  Commit:       97203d38ba

.NET SDKs installed:
  7.0.101 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 7.0.1 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0.1 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

Other architectures found:
  None

Environment variables:
  DOTNET_ROOT       [/usr/share/dotnet/]

global.json file:
  Not found

Learn more:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/info

Download .NET:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/download
```

```bash
osanhaji@5CD2068Y53:~ $ export DOTNET_ROOT=/usr/share/dotnet/
```

Answer (score 2):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-scripted-manual#scripted-install

If you let it install to `$HOME/.dotnet` it won't get found by others.  Instead put it in the `/opt` folder

Consider removing old dotnet stuff off the machine

```
sudo apt remove dotnet6 dotnet-sdk-6.0
sudo apt autoremove
```

```
# Download the dotnet install script
wget https://dot.net/v1/dotnet-install.sh -O dotnet-install.sh
chmod +x ./dotnet-install.sh

# Run it against a version you want, install to /opt
sudo ./dotnet-install.sh --channel 6.0 --install-dir /opt/dotnet

# Add it to everyone's path
echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/opt/dotnet' | sudo tee /etc/profile.d/dotnet.sh
sudo chmod +x /etc/profile.d/dotnet.sh
```

Test it:

```
$ which dotnet
/opt/dotnet/dotnet

$ dotnet --version
6.0.416
```

Comment: this helped - had to remove old net path $PATH then add it calling export PATH=$PATH:/opt/dotnet

Answer (score 1):

Even after fully uninstalling according to the instructions, I had `/etc/profile.d/dotnet.sh` pointing `DOTNET_ROOT` to `/usr/lib/dotnet`. I modified the file to point to `/usr/share/dotnet`. That fixed the issue for me. I guess the full uninstall didn't fully uninstall .NET.

Answer (score 1):

check

> **usr/share/dotnet**

directory and move all of the files/folders to

> **usr/lib/dotnet**

then you need to edit .**bashrc file** (located in ~) add following line

> **DOTNET_ROOT=/usr/lib/dotnet**

Answer (score 0):

Check list of dotnet versions installed on your machine and check for other than the SDK, if any other dotnet sdk/runtime is installed on your machine.

```
dotnet --list-sdks
```

If there is multiple dotnet versions installed, theres a chance your default dotnet version is pointing to other versions, So change it

```
dotnet new globaljson --sdk-version 6.0.400-1 --force
```

Also you use the *dotnet-core-uninstall* tool to remove the not-required version of dotnet to get rid of the version issue. Note that you have to install it manually as it not part of the sdk/runtime.

```
dotnet -core-uninstall --all-previews-but-latest --sdk
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be an issue with the latest version, i just removed dotnet entirely and reinstalled dotnet sdk 6.0 and everything is working again.
Be sure to use `sudo apt install dotnet-sdk-6.0` to specify the 6.0 version and not the latest