# Install of .net SDK not being recognized?

Tags: .net-core, .net-sdk

Check this:
[image]

I download the sdk from MS source, ran the SH script, it reports that the SDK is already installed, but then, no SDK listed, or `dotnet tool` available...

what am I missing?

Comment: Which distro is this? Tried on a fresh Ubuntu docker image and things ran correctly.

Comment: this is the official microsoft image for asp.net 7...

Comment: Open an issue in their github I guess.

Comment: maybe there are two different dotnet binaries on your machine? `which dotnet` vs I think the installer puts it into `$HOME/.dotnet`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73312785/dotnet-sdk-is-installed-but-not-recognized-linux-ubuntu-popos-22-04