# why is dotnet not found on ubuntu despite installing all the dotnet runtimes and sdk

Tags: .net-core, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-20.04, dotnet-cli

While running the `dotnet --version` on ubuntu cli, i am getting the following error.

ubuntu@ip-XXX-XX-XX-XXX:~$ dotnet --version

The command could not be loaded, possibly because:

- You intended to execute a .NET application:
  The application '--version' does not exist.
- You intended to execute a .NET SDK command:
  No .NET SDKs were found.

I am not able to check the version.

I have installed all the updates for the Ubuntu and docker, and then installed the following .net core modules.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install dotnet-sdk-7.0
sudo apt-get install dotnet-runtime-7.0
sudo apt-get install aspnetcore-runtime-7.0
```

I have connected to the Linux instance of EC2 from Windows with PuTTY.

However when I run the following command it gives me the installed runtimes,

```
ubuntu@ip-XXX-XX-XX-XXX:~$ dotnet --list-runtimes
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 7.0.11 [/usr/lib/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0.11 [/usr/lib/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

But, with the following command, it returns empty.

```
ubuntu@ip-XXX-XX-XX-XXX:~$ dotnet --list-sdks
ubuntu@ip-XXX-XX-XX-XXX:~$
```

What I am missing here? Why is `dotnet --version` not able to return the version and sdks are not found?

Comment: I don't know what was the problem and why it wasn't working but the answer from this post helped me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73312785/dotnet-sdk-is-installed-but-not-recognized-linux-ubuntu-popos-22-04/77059342#77059342